# Passing a PivotTable to a Function ByRef Error in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a simple function:

```
Function PtName(pt As PivotTable)
    PtName = pt.Name
End Function
```

In the immediate window I type the following:

```
set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
debug.Print PtName(pt)
```

And I get a ByRef argument type mismatch error. When I do this:

```
debug.Print typename(pt)
```

it returns `PivotTable`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really not sure what you are trying to do here.

```
Sub Test()
    s = PtName(ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)) ' Call function to assign pivottable name to variable "s"
    Debug.Print s
End Sub

Function PtName(pt As PivotTable)
    PtName = pt.Name
End Function
```

Returns: PivotTable1

You don't need this function, you could just do this.

```
Sub Test()
    s = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).Name
    Debug.Print s
End Sub
```

Which also Returns: PivotTable1

---

Also, you can't assign a variable in the Immediate window and try to reference it on a separate line of code if the program isn't even running.

Comment: This was a simplified version of a larger program I was trying to build. It's a macro in a personal workbook that would do some work on a specified pivot and return some data, but I am having trouble calling the function properly. I can't use a Sub because I need to be able to pass a PivotTable object from different workbooks. Looks like the problem was trying to reference an assigned variable in the Immediate window. Shame I can't do that, but that solved it with: debug.Print PtName(ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)). Thanks!